# Cygnus 0.10 Docker container

Tags: fiware-cygnus

Following the guidelines provided in GITHub,

I have tried to get the jar files, but I'm getting the following errors.

```
 sudo docker-compose -f ./docker/0.compose.jar-compiler.yml -p cygnus run --rm compiler
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building cygnus 0.10.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.2.01 has been relocated to xerces:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.6.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ cygnus ---
[INFO] Deleting /cygnus-compiler/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ cygnus ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ cygnus ---
[INFO] Compiling 44 source files to /cygnus-compiler/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /cygnus-compiler/src/main/java/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus/backends/hdfs/HDFSBackendImpl.java:[40,7] error: HDFSBackendImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method provisionHiveTable(FileFormat,String,String) in HDFSBackend
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.703 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-23T10:45:31+00:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/352M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project cygnus: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /cygnus-compiler/src/main/java/com/telefonica/iot/cygnus/backends/hdfs/HDFSBackendImpl.java:[40,7] error: HDFSBackendImpl is not abstract and does not override abstract method provisionHiveTable(FileFormat,String,String) in HDFSBackend
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

I run this command from the root of the repository:

docker-compose -f ./docker/0.compose.jar-compiler.yml -p cygnus run --rm compiler

Can anybody help me out on this?

Comment: Cygnus is currently in its  0.11.0 version. Can you provide us here the commit you are working on? (the output of `git rev-parse HEAD`)